# TB Mega Menu: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later

Tags: 8, version-control

I have installed drupal 8.0.2 on my hosting for testing purposes. I am using Zircon template and installed TB Mega Menu 8.x-1.0-alpha1. After installation, on page: admin/structure/tb-megamenu, when I click any of button, I get the following error:

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

by searching google, I came accross with a solution: https://www.drupal.org/node/2623306

But as a new to drupal and environment, I do not know how to do it. I have never tried patching before and most importantly it is the solution for the case.

If patching is the solution, which program should I use, how can I accomplish this step by step?

Comment: You can follow git document [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/git-instructions). Or simple way, go to file and edit code follow by file patch. - Symbol **"-"** you need delete this line. - Symbol **"+"** you add new line to code.